# ReferenceError because the variable is not being passed on

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

In my react native app I have a `ProductScreen` where two files get imported to complete the screen.

File 1 (`Products.js`) is my products list

File 2 (`Data.js`) is my data file (only temporary)

```
 import Products from '../../components/Products';
 import { shoes} from '../../Data';
```

---

In my `ProdcutScreen` I use the imported `Products` as a `component` and set the value of `products` to `shoes`

```
<Products products={shoes} onPress={this.props.addItemToCart}/>
```

---

Then in the `Product.js` file I try to set the `state` of my products list to products (which when called in the `ProdcutScreen` be set to `shoes`)

```
state = {
    products, 
    filteredProducts: products,
  };
```

---

This is where the **problem** comes into play, because I get the error

```
ReferenceError: ReferenceError: ReferenceError: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: products
```

The problem comes from line 16 in the `Products.js` file which is

```
state = {
        products, 
        filteredProducts: products,
      };
```

So It seems the value `shoes` which is collected from the `Data.js` file, is not getting passed on to the state.

---

My **question** is how can I pass this value on?

The list does work when I don't set the `state` and just render the list like this

```
{this.renderProducts(this.props.products)}
```

But I need to set the state because I want to be able to filter through my products.

---

**ProductScreen.js**

```
 import { drinks } from '../../Data';
 import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export  class ProductScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        headerTitle: 'shoes'
}




      render() {
        return (

            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Products products={shoes} onPress={this.props.addItemToCart}/> 
                <View >
                    {/* <TouchableOpacity style={styles.checkOutContainer} onPress={() => this.props.onPress(item)} > 
                        <Icon style={styles.checkmark} name="ios-checkmark" color="white" size={35} />
                    </TouchableOpacity> */}
                </View>
            </View>

        )
      }
    }
```

---

**Data.js**

```
export const shoes= [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Hurrace',
        brand: 'Nike',
        type: 'strong',
        price: 7,
    },
]
```

---

**Products.js**

```
class Products extends Component {

    state = {
        products, 
        filteredProducts: products,
      };

      setSearchText(event) {
        const searchText = event.nativeEvent.text;

        const textLength = this.state.products.length;

        const filteredTexts = this.state.products.filter(row => {
          return row.name.indexOf(searchText) !== -1;
        });
        console.log("text: " + JSON.stringify(filteredTexts));

        this.setState({
          searchText,
          filteredProducts: filteredTexts
        });
      }

    renderProducts = (products) => {
        console.log(products)

        return products.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <View key={index} style={styles.shoes}>

                    <View style={styles.text}>
                        <Text style={styles.name}>
                            {item.name}
                        </Text>

                        <Text style={styles.price}>
                        € {item.price}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.onPress(item)} > 
                        <Icon style={styles.button} name="ios-add" color="white" size={25} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            )
        })
    }
```

---

*I'm still learning react native, started a few months back.*

Comment: in your product screen component shoes data does not define

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use instance properties if you intend on using props as initial values. You need to do it via a constructor (Where you're passing in props):

```
class Products extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const { products } = this.props;
        this.state = {
            products, 
            filteredProducts: products,
        };
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it was done that way. I directly delved into contructors after your comment, and it also helped me :)